Is there a way to fix ModuleNotFound error?
I've tried reinstalling trimesh multiple times but no luck. I'm on mac.
import trimesh
import numpy as np

# Load a mesh from a file
mesh = trimesh.load('path/to/your/mesh.obj')

# Display some basic information about the mesh
print(f"Mesh: {mesh.metadata['file_name']}")
print(f"Number of vertices: {len(mesh.vertices)}")
print(f"Number of faces: {len(mesh.faces)}")

# Render the mesh
mesh.show()

terminal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'trimesh'


Make sure you install it in the same python / environment as where you then run your script.

How have you installed trimesh? Are you using the correct python interpreter for where you’ve installed the package.

how do i do that?

I installed trimesh through pip. I'm using pylance and python 3.12

Its been a week since I asked the question can I get some help. I can even run basic python scripts.
